# Smartphone keeps reloading webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I have an issue where a webpage is reloaded (refreshed) automaticaly on smartphones. This is not a desired reload. It only happens on mobile (chrome developper tools -> Device mode -> Google Nexus 4) and hit refresh.

http://lavenuecondos.com/fr/

Same happens on localhost, screenshots are from localhost. I don't know if it's a script that does this. It wasn't the case a month ago.

Thank you for your help.

[image: Expected render on Nexus 4]
[image: Actual render on Nexus 4]
[image: See 31 'Navigated to' in Console]

Comment: You can rate -1 if you want, but please at least help by saying why.

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprid, a line in js write_cookie function

```
 writeCookie();
    function writeCookie()
    {
        the_cookie = document.cookie;
        if( the_cookie ){
            if( window.devicePixelRatio >= 2 ){
                the_cookie = "pixel_ratio="+window.devicePixelRatio+";"+the_cookie;
                document.cookie = the_cookie;
                //location = ''; //this line was culprid
            }
        }
    }
```